# How direct mapping works for a given memory address?

Tags: caching, memory, mapping, cpu-architecture

I was reading `Direct Mapping Cache Organization` from the book `Computer Architecture and Organization` by `William Stallings`. It has this figure:
[image: Direct Mapping]

I wanted to simulate the operation for a 16 `block` sized `main memory` where each `block` has 2 `words`. My cache `would` have 4 `lines` then. Now here's the figure:
[image: 32 word main Memory]

Now my first question is, How `Tag` is generated in the cache for a `block` of `main memory`? For example, what would be the `tag` and `line` numbers and for the data of this cache table:

[image: 8 word cache]

My second question is, how data are found for the memory locations: `1101`, `0101`,`0010`,`1111`. Since `0010` is already in the cache, what happens when it is called? I just want to know the steps to find data in these memory addresses whether they are in cache or not.